# Python3 code to add the square brackets at the start of text and end of the json text

Tags: python-3.x

I have json file and data is
{"name": "Hi22", "description": "Ca12", "false_positives": "NA121", "query": "himanshu11"},
{"name": "we", "description": "wew", "false_positives": "ewe", "query": "ww}

I want the output as :
[{"name": "Hi22", "description": "Ca12", "false_positives": "NA121", "query": "himanshu11"},
{"name": "we", "description": "wew", "false_positives": "ewe", "query": "ww}
]

Comment: `new_json_object = [old_json_object]` that will be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
aTuple = {"name": "Hi22", "description": "Ca12", "false_positives": "NA121", "query": "himanshu11"}, {"name": "we", "description": "wew", "false_positives": "ewe", "query": "ww"}

aList = list(aTuple)

#print list
print(type(aList))
print(aList)
```

output:

```
[{'query': 'himanshu11', 'description': 'Ca12', 'false_positives': 'NA121', 'name': 'Hi22'}, {'query': 'ww', 'description': 'wew', 'false_positives': 'ewe', 'name': 'we'}]
```